# SQL JOIN to omit other columns after first result

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Here is the result I need, simplified:

```
select name, phonenumber
from contacttmp
left outer join phonetmp on (contacttmp.id = phonetmp.contact_id);

 name  | phonenumber
-------+--------------
 bob   | 111-222-3333
 bob   | 111-222-4444
 bob   | 111-222-5555
 frank | 111-222-6666
 joe   | 111-222-7777
```

The query, however displays the name, I'm trying to omit the name after the first result:

```
 name  | phonenumber
-------+--------------
 bob   | 111-222-3333
       | 111-222-4444
       | 111-222-5555
 frank | 111-222-6666
 joe   | 111-222-7777
```

Here's how I made the example tables and the data:

```
create table contacttmp (id serial, name text);
create table phonetmp (phoneNumber text, contact_id integer);

select * from contacttmp;
 id | name
----+-------
  1 | bob
  2 | frank
  3 | joe

select * from phonetmp ;
 phonenumber  | contact_id
--------------+------------
 111-222-3333 |          1
 111-222-4444 |          1
 111-222-5555 |          1
 111-222-6666 |          2
 111-222-7777 |          3
```

#### Old part of question

I'm working on a contacts program in PHP and a requirement is to display the results but omit the other fields after the first record is displayed if there are multiple results of that same record.

From the [postgres tutorial join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-join.html) examples I'm doing something like this with a left outer join:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather LEFT OUTER JOIN cities ON (weather.city = cities.name);

    city      | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date    |     name      | location
--------------+---------+---------+------+------------+---------------+-----------
Hayward       |      37 |      54 |      | 1994-11-29 |               |
San Francisco |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27 | San Francisco | (-194,53)
San Francisco |      43 |      57 |    0 | 1994-11-29 | San Francisco | (-194,53)
```

I can't figure out how to, or if it is possible to, alter the above query to not display the other fields after the first result.

For example, if we add the clause "WHERE location = '(-194,53)'" we don't want the second (and third if there is one) results to display the columns other than location, so the query (plus something extra) and the result would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather LEFT OUTER JOIN cities ON (weather.city = cities.name)
WHERE location = '(-194,53)';

    city      | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date    |     name      | location
--------------+---------+---------+------+------------+---------------+-----------
San Francisco |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27 | San Francisco | (-194,53)
              |         |         |      |            |               | (-194,53)
```

Is this possible with some kind of JOIN or exclusion or other query? Or do I have to remove these fields in PHP after getting all the results (would rather not do).

To avoid confusion, I'm required to achieve a result set like:

```
    city      | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date    |     name      | location
--------------+---------+---------+------+------------+---------------+-----------
San Francisco |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27 | San Francisco | (-194,53)
              |         |         |      |            |               | (-19,5)
              |         |         |      |            |               | (-94,3)
Philadelphia  |    55   |   60    | 0.1  | 1995-12-12 | Philadelphia  | (-1,1)
              |         |         |      |            |               | (-77,55)
              |         |         |      |            |               | (-3,33)
```

Where any additional results for the same record (city) with different locations would only display the different location.

Comment: Why would you want to lose all that information?  It is not duplicated.

Comment: In my case all the data is duplicated, its for contacts, so a join with another table results in all the columns being the same except for a phone number which is coming from the second table. The requirement is that I display the first record with the first phone number, then after that, just the phone number in phone column and nothing else.

Comment: Your example probably isn't the best, since cities don't generally have multiple locations like that. They can have multiple temperature readings at different dates, though.

Comment: Your example is broken. First you indicate duplicates on `location`, then you add a `WHERE` clause excluding all other values for `location`, and finally you want something *completely different*. Please fix your question to make sense. At least provide table definitions, so we know where columns come from.

Comment: I made a new simple example at the top of the question, I hope it makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the slightly modified test case in the fiddle below.

#### Simple case

For the simple case dealing with a **single column** from each column, comparing to the *previous* row with the window function `lag()` does the job:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN lag(c.contact) OVER (ORDER BY c.contact, p.phone_nr)
               = c.contact THEN NULL ELSE c.contact END
     , p.phone_nr
FROM   contact c
LEFT   JOIN phone p USING (contact_id);
```

You could repeat that for *n columns*, but that's tedious

#### For many columns

```
SELECT c.*, p.phone_nr
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY contact_id ORDER BY phone_nr) AS rn
   FROM   phone
   ) p
LEFT  JOIN contact c ON c.contact_id = p.contact_id AND p.rn = 1;
```

Something like a "reverse LEFT JOIN". This is assuming referential integrity (no missing rows in `contact`. Also, contacts without any entries in `phone` are not in the result. Easy to add if need should be.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef550/1)

Aside, your query in the first example exhibits a rookie mistake.

```
SELECT * FROM weather LEFT OUTER JOIN cities ON (weather.city = cities.name)
WHERE location = '(-194,53)';
```

One does not combine a `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause on the right table. Doesn't makes sense. Details:

- [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)

Except to test for existence ...

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this type of logic in SQL, but it is not recommended.  The result set from SQL queries is in a table format.  Tables represented unordered sets and generally have all columns meaning the same thing.

So, having a result set that depends on the values from the "preceding" row is not a proper way to use SQL.  Although you can get this result in Postgres, I do not recommend it.  Usually, this type of formatting is done on the application side.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if I was missing a way of using joins or something else to accomplish this.

Comment: `but it is not recommended` .. `not a proper way to use SQL.` Let's just say, this is *one* opinion. Here's another: This is just another task that may be simple to solve in a client. It's simple enough in the database. Query results do not represent unordered sets. An opinion that does not try to provide an answer should be a comment, btw.

Comment: I rarely down vote but I don't think this really answers the question particular since you say it can be done but shouldn't and you provide no details on how or code wise. IMO Your answers a comment.

Comment: @AdamGent . . . The OP is learning SQL.  There is no simple way to just make a "join" do what s/he wants.  You *can* get the desired result in SQL, but it is not really helpful to the OP to show a complicated expression with window functions and lots of `case` statements.

Comment: Ostensibly his knowledge of SQL is not bad since he does include proper join statements. One could even argue that not sending duplicate data as on optimization. My point still stands given you provide no code or actual technical solution it would be better served as a comment.

Comment: @AdamGent . . . "From the postgres tutorial join examples I'm doing something like this with a left outer join:"

Comment: And here is another quote: *"Or do I have to remove these fields in PHP after getting all the results **(would rather not do)**."*. Clearly you don't need the rep points so why not do the right thing and let the better answer (Bruno's) ahead ie delete and make a comment.

Comment: @AdamGent . . . If you look at the edit history, you will see the question that I answered.  It is much less detailed than the question there now and it doesn't have that quote in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid repeating the same information, you can use a window function that tells you the position of that row in the group (a `PARTITION` for this purpose, not a group in the `GROUP BY` sense), then hide the text for the columns you don't want to repeat if that position in the group is greater than 1.

```
WITH joined_results AS (
   SELECT
      w.city, c.location, w.temp_lo, w.temp_hi, w.prcp, w.date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.city, c.location ORDER BY date) AS pos
   FROM weather w
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cities c ON (w.city = c.name)
   ORDER BY w.city, c.location
)
SELECT
   CASE WHEN pos > 1 THEN '' ELSE city END,
   CASE WHEN pos > 1 THEN '' ELSE location END,
   temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp, date
FROM joined_results;
```

This should give you this:

```
     city      | location  | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date    
---------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+------------
 Hayward       |           |      37 |      54 |      | 1994-11-29
 San Francisco | (-194,53) |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27
               |           |      43 |      57 |    0 | 1994-11-29
```

To understand what `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.city, c.location ORDER BY date) AS pos` does, it probably worth looking at what you get with `SELECT * FROM joined_results`:

```
     city      | location  | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date    | pos 
---------------+-----------+---------+---------+------+------------+-----
 Hayward       |           |      37 |      54 |      | 1994-11-29 |   1
 San Francisco | (-194,53) |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27 |   1
 San Francisco | (-194,53) |      43 |      57 |    0 | 1994-11-29 |   2
```

After that, just replace what you don't want with white space using `CASE WHEN pos > 1 THEN '' ELSE ... END`.

(This being said, it's something I'd generally prefer to do in the presentation layer rather than in the query.)

Comment: Note that this'll work, but it'll be quite a bit slower to execute than just returning all the info.