# How to convert IN and NOT IN subselect to JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I have:

```
with cm as (select n from tbl1 where c = 41)    
select nn from tbl2  
where 
    n in (select n from cm) and
    nn not in (select n from cm);
```

This conversion does not seem to work:

```
 select tbl2.nn from tbl2 join tbl1
 on tbl1.n = tbl2.n and tbl1.n != tbl2.nn
 where tbl1.c = 41;
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way, you have to join to the same table twice.
With joins instead of `IN`:

```sql
WITH cm AS (SELECT n FROM tbl1 WHERE c = 41)
SELECT t.nn
FROM   tbl2    t
JOIN   cm      c1 ON c1.n = t.n
LEFT   JOIN cm c2 ON c2.n = t.nn
WHERE  c2.n IS NULL;
```

The same without CTE:

```sql
SELECT t.nn
FROM   tbl2      t
JOIN   tbl1      t1 USING (n)  -- equivalent to "ON t1.n = t.n" here
LEFT   JOIN tbl1 t2 ON t2.n = t.nn
                   AND t2.c = 41  -- must go here!
WHERE  t1.c = 41
AND    t2.n IS NULL;
```

Requires that `cm.n` is `UNIQUE` / `tbl1.n` is `UNIQUE` for `tbl1.c = 41`.

See:

- [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)
- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

While `cm.n` is never `NULL`, your original works, too:

```sql
WITH cm AS (SELECT n FROM tbl1 WHERE c = 41)
SELECT t.nn
FROM   tbl2 t
WHERE  n      IN (TABLE cm)
AND    nn NOT IN (TABLE cm);
```

Simplified with short syntax `TABLE`. See:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)

But I'd rather use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. Typically faster and does not fail surprisingly with `NULL` values.

```sql
WITH cm AS (SELECT n FROM tbl1 WHERE c = 41)
SELECT t.nn
FROM   tbl2 t
WHERE  EXISTS     (SELECT FROM cm WHERE n = t.n)
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM cm WHERE n = t.nn)
```

`EXISTS` never duplicates rows (like `IN`). And it works as expected when NULL values are involved (like `JOIN`). So it's typically my first choice.

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)