# Fetch all data from a table and related status from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a table `master_account` like so

| _id | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3067261 |
| 2 | 4327735 |
| 3 | 8521420 |

and another table `affiliate_partners` like so

| _id | account_id | partner_account_id | is_client | is_driver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3067261 | 4327735 | true | true |
| 2 | 4327735 | 3067261 | true | true |
| 3 | 8521420 | 4327735 | false | false |

I'm logging in my application as `account_id 3067261` and I get to see a list of all the accounts in `master_account` except for `account_id 3067261` which is mine. At the same time I need to see the statuses(`is_client`, `is_driver`) for my `account_id 3067261` which are in `affiliate_partners` related to my account_id. Till now, I have tried this query but it returns null for all the statuses(`is_client`, `is_driver`) and I do need `null` for the `account_id` for those who aren't connected in the `affiliate_partners` table.

```
SELECT 
        ma._id,
        ma.account_id, 
        CASE 
        WHEN ma.account_id = '3067261'
        THEN ap.is_client
        ELSE null
        END as is_client,
        CASE 
        WHEN ma.account_id = '3067261'
        THEN ap.is_driver
        ELSE null
        END as is_driver
from master_account ma
left join affiliate_partners ap
on ma.account_id = ap.account_id
where ma.account_id != '3067261'
```

Expected result for the above sample:

| _id | account_id | is_client | is_driver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4327735 | true | true |
| 3 | 8521420 | false | false |

But instead I get:

| _id | account_id | is_client | is_driver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4327735 | null | null |
| 3 | 8521420 | null | null |

Comment: Please provide your expected results for the sample data.

Comment: This code fragment is broken: `CASE WHEN ap.account_id = ma.account_id` Please, your Postgres version and table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints). And your explanation does not seem clear, yet.

Comment: Apologies, let me fix the query.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need a predicate in the join condition of your `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT ma.*, ap.is_client, ap.is_driver
FROM   master_account ma
LEFT   JOIN affiliate_partners ap ON ma.account_id = ap.partner_account_id
                                 AND ap.account_id = '3067261'  -- !!
WHERE  ma.account_id <> '3067261';
```

This way, you also don't need `CASE` expressions. `is_client` and `is_driver` are `NULL` if there is no related row in `affiliate_partners` with `partner_account_id = '3067261'`
(Also, you had `ma.account_id` instead of `ap.account_id`.)

See:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)
- [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)

Comment: I just changed ma.account_id = ap.account_id to ```on ma.account_id = ap.partner_account_id``` and now im getting the desired result

Comment: In this case, you also need to flip the 2nd condition. See update. (And your displayed result is still incorrect.)