Using Aggregates on Multiple related tables removes rows without relation
I have a postgresql database I am trying to query and this is my current code:
SELECT r.id, r.band_id, r.title, r.imageURL, v.rating, b.name AS bandname, l.price
                FROM records r
                JOIN bands b ON b.id=r.band_id
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT record_id, AVG(rating)::NUMERIC(10,1) as rating
                            FROM reviews
                            GROUP BY record_id) v
                            ON v.record_id = r.id
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT record_id, MIN(price) as price
                            FROM listings
                            GROUP BY record_id) l
                            ON l.record_id = r.id

It feels much slower and clunkier than it needs to be.
SELECT r.id, r.band_id, r.title, r.imageURL, b.name AS bandname, 
MIN(l.price) AS price, AVG(rating)::NUMERIC(10,1) as rating
                FROM records r
                JOIN bands b ON b.id=r.band_id
                JOIN listings l ON l.record_id = r.id
                JOIN reviews v ON v.record_id = r.id
                GROUP BY r.id, r.band_id, r.title, r.imageURL, b.name

Is the query I want to use, as it looks nicer and I think would be more efficient, the big problem however, is that this query will not include any records that do not have at least one corresponding row in each of the reviews and listings tables. I do not understand why that is the case.
I have tried the above code in a few different other variations, the goal here is get all the information of the record as well as the Average rating, lowest price, and band name based off the joined databases, while keeping records that do not currently have any related reviews or listings.
I am an amateur, but feel like I have a good grasp on how the sub-queries work, and why there is a need for the GROUP BY statement without them, but I am having a hard time understanding why the second code snippet omits the records that do not have at least one row in the corresponding relation instead of just providing it as NULL. I am also having a hard time accepting I may have to use the longer, uglier, and (to the best of my knowledge) slower query for my needs.

The first one uses LEFT Join which includes all records from band and the matching one from the sub queries of reviews and listing.second query is an INNER join which will only bring the common records between the tables,which might be the cause of missing records

Change the second query to use LEFT JOIN with both reviews and listings. If id is the primary key of records, then the GROUP BY list can be simplified to just r.id since PostgreSQL knows that all columns in records are dependent on id (keep in mind that not all databases support this).

Does this could answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de

Using LEFT JOIN completely fixed the query, thank you so much! postgres still required the GROUP BY of v.rating and band name, but it functions as expected now. I very simply overlooked the fact that JOIN is a default inner join.
I am still curious as to whether I am right in my assertion that the smaller query is more efficient.

Your second query simply isn't ever going to give you correct results.
Your immediate issue is solved simply by changing the two JOINs to LEFT JOIN, however that will still give you invalid results, because it causes a cartesian cross-join between both one-to-many relations. In other words, you can only use such a GROUP BY query when only a single one-to-many relation is involved, not multiple.
You can simplify your existing query a little bit by using LATERAL joins (in SQL Server this would be an OUTER APPLY).
SELECT
  r.id,
  r.band_id,
  r.title,
  r.imageURL,
  v.rating,
  b.name AS bandname,
  l.price
FROM records r
JOIN bands b ON b.id = r.band_id
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT AVG(rating::NUMERIC(10,1)) as rating  -- prob need to convert BEFORE averaging
    FROM reviews rv
    WHERE rv.record_id = r.id
) ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT MIN(price) as price
    FROM listings l
    WHERE l.record_id = r.id
) ON 1=1


I appreciate the feedback, but in changing the JOIN to LEFT JOIN I was able to get the query working as expected, testing with multiple ratings and prices I have run into no issues.
But you said that the query will still give invalid results, do you think there are any issues I will run into in the future using that method?

Yes, the only reason it "works" now is because the data isn't an issue, also MIN is not affacted by the cartesian join. But try do SUM or COUNT (when you have multiple ratings and multiple prices per record) and you will see the results are incorrect.

That makes a lot of sense, thank you. I do see where especially COUNT would be incorrect if used with this query, I didn't think about that before.
